# SQL - Postgres - How to return max and min value only for a column value - Unique table

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, min

I would like return only min value et max for id values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT true_table.id_crsp ,
true_table.type_orientation as type_orientation_apres_requalif,
CONCAT(to_char(true_table.ts_crea, 'DD-MM-YYYY - HH24hMI')) AS date_requalif,
CONCAT(to_char(false_table.ts_crea, 'DD-MM-YYYY - HH24hMI')) AS date_creation,
AGE (true_table.ts_crea::timestamp, false_table.ts_crea::timestamp) as intervalle_creation_requalif
FROM mydb as false_table 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE in_requalification= TRUE) as true_table 
ON false_table.id_crsp = true_table.id_crsp
AND false_table.in_requalification = FALSE
order by intervalle_creation_requalif asc;
```

- in_requalification  is boolean
- id_crsp  is String
- ts_crea is Timestamp

This request return the id_crsp who has the boolean in false AND true.
But I have my "intervalle_creation_requalif" in negative, because I need to retrieve max value for "requalif" and min for the last date in false_table WITH THIS REQUEST.

So : get min value for "date_creation" and max value for "date_requalif".

Thanks

Comment: If you want to get the min or max value, why don't you use the functions MIN or MAX? They always return one value only. And this is exactly your intention, isn't it? Would be great if you show some sample input and expected result.

Comment: Because it doesnt work with postgres in the select or at the end with a "and"